# Trouble understanding AngularJS Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I'm currently learning AngularJS and I'm having trouble translating a piece of code from an example to my own code.

In the following example from [Urish](http://urish.org/angular/AngularPromises.pdf), I understand that the variable promise must contain the functions and queries necessary for the rest of the function to execute.

```
var promise = asyncFunction(parameters); 

promise.then( 
function (result) { 
 // Do Something with the result 
}, 
function (error) { 
 // Handle error (exception, etc). 
});
```

So in my case, if I want to first make two $http queries and with the data received populate the url of a third query, would it be something like this?

```
var promise = $scope.getDetails(id); 

  $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
      success(function(data) {
          $scope.artist = data;
      });
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100').
      success(function(data2) {
          $scope.releases = data2.releases;
      });
    $scope.clicked = true;
    $scope.sliding = true;
  } 

  promise.then( 
    $scope.getImages = function (title, name) {
        $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json').
          success(function(data4) {
              $scope.images = data4;
          });
    },
  function (error) { 
   // Handle error (exception, etc). 
  });
```

Is this the right approach? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: I've created a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK5LDpxHj5NBwOlvNS3z?p=preview) with Benjamins solution, but the AngularJS brakes. Any idea where the issue might be?

Comment: `getDetails` needs to return a promise. `$http.get` returns one but since you call it twice you need to combine them with [`all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Answer (score 2):

In order to combine promises, like Florian suggested you should use [`.all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#all):

```
$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
    var api = 'http://api.discogs.com/artists/';
    return $q.all([$http.get(api + id),
                  $http.get(api + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100')]);
});
```

Then usage is:

```
$scope.getDetails(YOURID).then(function(results){
    $scope.artist = results[0];
    $scope.releases = results[1].releases;
});
```

Or in the three queries example:

```
$scope.getDetails(YOURID).then(function(results){
    $scope.artist = results[0];
    $scope.releases = results[1].releases;
    // data for getImages available here
    return $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?...' + results[0]...
});
```

(Also, I'd put it in a service)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, the only piece of your code that I don't get is (YOURID). Which id is that??

Comment: The ID you want to get the details for :)

Comment: I've tried it in my example and in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK5LDpxHj5NBwOlvNS3z?p=preview), but so far no luck : /

Answer (score 1):

```
  $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
    $scope.clicked = true;
    $scope.sliding = true;
return $q.all(    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
      success(function(data) {
          $scope.artist = data;
      }),
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=100').
      success(function(data2) {
          $scope.releases = data2.releases;
      }));
}
```

You must accept $q as a dependency for the controller. $q.all() takes multiple promises and returns a promise which resolves or gets rejected depending upon the passed in promises. Read about $q at
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
You can do

```
var promise = $scope.getDetails(id);
promise.then(...,...);
```